# Ag Grid + React: Server Side - When new row is added grid does not auto update

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using a variety of rowModelTypes in my application, but I notice for server side the grid doesn't auto update, only if you click out and in of the grid, or else implement a function to purge / refresh the grid.

I need the capabilities of serverSide but would also like the grid to auto update on a new row, such as the way viewport does. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand so far you have one component for showing data table and one from which this component is calling. Do one thing, if new row added but before it you must update some variable for that row? is it ? so set that whole array in state in table component and map on that state so that whenever new row added it will automatically reflect on table. If you have other scenarios then put your code here.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer -

Yes I have one component for showing the grid, and then the Grid itself.

I have different grids with different row model types for different purposes. With server side, when a new row is added the grid does not auto update, only on refresh or filter.

Answer (score 0):

try using `gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ add: newItems });` to add item to grid.

if this doesn't work please try to recreate a working plunkr/JSFiddle so that we can help better.